# remove all non floating point or an int in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string `"$AS!$1.2,1.4nva&(1.0"` and I want to format it like this.. `"1.2, 1.4, 1.0"`

How to do these with regex? And if it may.. Can you state how to read it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
"$AS!$1.2,1.4nva&(1.0".match(/\d+\.\d+/g).join(', ');
```

Output:

```
"1.2, 1.4, 1.0"
```

Comment: `\d+` matches one or more digits; `\.` matches dot  `g` means grep (find all occurrences)

Comment: What's the difference without a plus sign? Cause I've tried to removed the plus sign and it works.

Comment: `\d` matches one digit; `\d+` matches one or more.